# MVC 5 - Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem where my controller method is being called but it is not having the required parameter value passed to it: Any ideas where I am going wrong? (at the moment the "query" parameter is null).

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Search(string query, int page = 1)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)) return SearchResults(query, page);
    return View(new ApplicationSearchViewModel());
}
```

**View HTML**

```
@model BluBrik.Mobile.WebUI.Models.ApplicationSearchViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Find Application";
}

<h2>Search</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResults", "Application", new { query = Model.SearchString }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SearchString)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

**Route.config**

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: null,
        url: "Application/Search/{query}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Application", action = "Search", query = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: The first time your view loads, does your Model.SearchString have a value:
new { query = Model.SearchString }

Comment: No, Model.SearchString is an auto-property that is typed into the view after it has loaded

Comment: Try this in your form, 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchString, new { id = "query", name="query" })
 And Remove this , new { query = Model.SearchString  from your @Html.BeginForm()
I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: And make your form method as get

Comment: Above suggestions applied and still same result.

Comment: May I ask why you are using route to post back a form?

Comment: You've passed the action name "SearchResults" to your Html.BeginForm(). According to your route config and action method name, that should be just "Search". Try that in addition to the above suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far but I think I need to go back to the start and understand what I'm trying to achieve! - this is my first real attempt at asp.net MVC and I'm getting myself in a right muddle at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML for the form element will be created when the page is loaded, not when it is posted back. Therefore your Model.SearchString value in the querystring will not reflect the value in the posted form.

You need to use the post data. You may also want to consider two controller actions, for GET and POST. This would give you:

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string query, int page = 1)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)) return SearchResults(query, page);
    return View(new ApplicationSearchViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(ApplicationSearchViewModel model)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.SearchString)) return SearchResults(model.SearchString , 1);
    return View(new ApplicationSearchViewModel());
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Application", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SearchString)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Having stripped back my code and run through my notes again I got my code working as I'd expect. However, this I believe would be the "correct" way to do it and I will revisit my code again later with this in mind. Thanks